# Set up onion server with Dart (Flutter) on Smartphones

Tags: java, android, flutter, server

I am looking for a way to set up a hidden service v3 on a smartphone with Flutter. I have already looked at the project [utopic_tor_onion_proxy](https://github.com/utopicnarwhal/utopic_tor_onion_proxy) on github, but I want to use the torproject binaries directly and it is also not possible to handle requests.
For some tips on how to do this with for example a Flutter plugin I would be very grateful.
Also I would be glad about a small code example.

I was already able to create a server and reach it with the following code:

```
class MyServer {  

void main(List<String> args) async {
// Use any available host or container IP (usually `0.0.0.0`).
final ip = InternetAddress.anyIPv4;

// Configure a pipeline that logs requests.
final _handler = Pipeline().addMiddleware(logRequests()).addHandler(_router);

// For running in containers, we respect the PORT environment variable.
final port = int.parse(Platform.environment['PORT'] ?? '5555');
final server = await serve(_handler, ip, port);
print('Server listening on port ${server.port}');


 }}
```